# As + adjective + a/an + noun

Tags: grammar

Back in the days of the Roman Empire, being the top dog was just **as risky a business** and assassination was an occupational hazard.

The phrase "as risky a business":
 1. What does it mean? (or maybe the general meaning of this structure?)

2. What is this structure? Is it a compare structure like [as + adj + as]? If yes, why don't they write "as risky as a business" but "as risky a business"? If no, could you please explain it further?
3. I have looked up in the dictionary and it said "risky business" = dangerous. If so, is it possible to paraphrase this to: ....being a top dog was a risky business? And as they write "risky a business" with "a" in between the phrase, won't it make the meaning of this phrase different?
   Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE! If you had any questions about the policies of our community, you can visit ‎‎[the help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) or take a ‎‎[tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) of the website.‎‎

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's short for "as risky a business" [as it is now]. The comparason is not vs. "business" or some other business, but vs. some other time.